# get dynamic generated content after using curl to login

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, curl, dynamic

I know that curl does not execute javascript, it only grabs static html, so this is why a simple curl will not work for me.
I do not know much about php, I'm new to this, but what I understand so for is that if I did not have to first login to grab the content I can simple use file_get_contents witch will first execute the dynamic content and then grab the html content, witch in return give me what I need, but I first have to login and then get the page.
I tried to login using curl

```
$user = "myuser";
$pass = "mypassword";

//create cookie file
$random = rand(0,9999999);
$cookie = $random."cookie.txt";
$fp = fopen("$cookie","w") or die("<BR><B>Unable to open cookie file $cookie_file_path for write!<BR>");
fclose($fp);

//do login using curl
$LOGINURL = "https://controlpanel.example.com/index.html";
$agent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:29.0) Gecko/20120101 Firefox/29.0";
$v2 = array( 'userName'=>$user, 'password'=>$pass);
$reffer = "https://www.google.com";
//this first call is to set the cookie
$ch = curl_init(); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$LOGINURL);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $agent);
ob_start();      // Prevent output
curl_exec ($ch);
ob_end_clean();  // End preventing output
curl_close ($ch);
unset($ch);
//now that the cookie is set, do login
$ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$v2); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookie);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$LOGINURL);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $reffer);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $agent);

$result = curl_exec($ch);

//now we are logged-in
//now grab the page you need

$profileurl = 'https://controlpanel.example.com/information.html';
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $profileurl);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 5);

$result = curl_exec ($ch);
```

But this will only get the static html, not the dynamic content too.
Let me explain better.
The code I get, at this point using above curl method, in $result is:

```
.....
<div id="DisplayAccountInfo"><span class="loading">Loading info</span></div>
.....
```

If I do this manually using firefox and inspect element with firebug the source is:

```
.....
<div id="DisplayAccountInfo">
  <div class="formModule" id="formContainer">
    ......
       <legend>Your code for this hour is 8T5D9LO</legend>
    .....
  </div>
</div>
.....
```

What I notice in firebug console is:

```
GET https://controlpanel.example.com/async/information.html

200 OK
        669ms   
jquery-....min.js (line 19)
```

What I, as a noob, understand from this is that the content is dinamicly loaded using jquery, and curl does not know how to do that.

I tried to put instead of

```
$profileurl = 'https://controlpanel.example.com/information.html';
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $profileurl);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 5);

$result = curl_exec ($ch);

//replaced the above with this
$result = file_get_contents($profileurl);
```

but I get the html from login page because I think it does not recognize anymore that I'm logged in.

So how can I solve this? Can you please help me?

Comment: You understand wrong, file_get_contents wont execue javascript. Nothing built into php will. Your options are 1) manually parse the returned source, work out the javascript endpoints and make calls directly to them or 2) install a headless browser like phantomjs, that does execute javascript

Comment: this question is tagged as jquery, can you use jquery? if so you might consider simple solution using http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/

Comment: user574632 I see that people tend to redirect to phantomjs, but how do I use it? I was looking at documentation but I do not know how to use it.

Comment: Kyborek I put jquery because, as said I'm new to this, and I thought that dynamic content is jquery or ajax. What I need is to grab that page and I do not care how.

Comment: I changed my initial question to explained better what the problems is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

haha, so easy it did not cross my mind.
For me it is simple, I did not have to call

https://controlpanel.example.com/information.html

but

https://controlpanel.example.com/async/information.html

to get the div I wanted :)

Lucky for me I noticed the get function in firebug :)

So the cod now is :

```
$user = "myuser";
$pass = "mypassword";

//create cookie file
$random = rand(0,9999999);
$cookie = $random."cookie.txt";
$fp = fopen("$cookie","w") or die("<BR><B>Unable to open cookie file $cookie for write!<BR>");
fclose($fp);

//do login using curl
$LOGINURL = "https://controlpanel.example.com/index.html";
$agent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:29.0) Gecko/20120101 Firefox/29.0";
$v2 = array( 'userName'=>$user, 'password'=>$pass);
$reffer = "https://www.google.com";
//this first call is to set the cookie

$ch = curl_init(); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$LOGINURL);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $agent);
ob_start();      // Prevent output
curl_exec ($ch);
ob_end_clean();  // End preventing output
curl_close ($ch);
unset($ch);

//now that the cookie is set, do login
$ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$v2); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookie);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$LOGINURL);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $reffer);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $agent);

$result = curl_exec($ch);

//now we are logged-in
//now grab the page you need

$profileurl = 'https://controlpanel.example.com/async/information.html';
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $profileurl);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 0);

$result = curl_exec ($ch);
```

Answer (score 1):

I think I got what you're doing.

The key point here is, most website handle login with cookie. In https://controlpanel.example.com/information.html, if the website set a cookie after you login in your browser, then the good news is you can solve this problem.

The problem in your code is, PHP won't set cookie for you.

You need 2 steps:

Step 1. You need to obtain the cookie when your php curl the login

Here's how you get cookie header returned from the login page.

```
$ch = curl_init('https://controlpanel.example.com/index.html');

....

$result = curl_exec($ch);
preg_match('/^Set-Cookie:\s*([^;]*)/mi', $result, $m);
parse_str($m[1], $cookies);
echo $cookies;//See if you've successfully obtained the return cookie
```

Step 2. You access https://controlpanel.example.com/information.html with the cookie you obtained in step 1. (like you've already did in your own code)

Comment: I will try it, I do not have time now, I will let you know.

Comment: but don't I already do that in my first curl request? is that code not for setting the cookie?

Comment: I changed my initial question to explained better what the problems is